# Is it possable to add or take away dom elements based on the data given by the API

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wondering if It is possible to render dom elements in without having to write code for them in the HTML like a builder of some sort

For example if I am an admin user and decide that I want to add a new form for my users I toggle a button on my end and the API sends that data to the user's end and renders the dom dynamically for the necessary dom elements so the user can input that data and send it back to be stored in a database.

Or am I only able to do it by writing the code in the HTML and hiding it with a ngIf statement It would be something like Ms Sharepoint

Thank you in Advance

Comment: It's definitely possible, but I'm not sure Angular is suited for that. Maybe you should use a server-side language instead ?

Comment: That's what I was thinking but what language would render the html based on the API data sent

Comment: Well that's my point, maybe you should not use an API and stick to the "old way", like PHP ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use *ngIf. Create new boolean variable and based on API data set it's value as true/false. Display/hide DOM elements based on this variable using *ngIf

Comment: Ive done that but what Im asking is it possible to do it without ngif

Comment: As an alternative to ngIf, you can create 2 different components with different template and render these components dynamically based on data by using ComponentFactoryResolver